# Pyspark groupBy Pivot Transformation

Tags: pyspark, pivot, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a hard time framing the following Pyspark dataframe manipulation.

Essentially I am trying to group by category and then pivot/unmelt the subcategories and add new columns.

[image]

I've tried a number of ways, but they are very slow and and are not leveraging Spark's parallelism.

Here is my existing (slow, verbose) code:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = sqlContext.table('Table')

#loop over category
listids = [x.asDict().values()[0] for x in df.select("category").distinct().collect()]
dfArray = [df.where(df.category == x) for x in listids]
for d in dfArray:
  #loop over subcategory
  listids_sub = [x.asDict().values()[0] for x in d.select("sub_category").distinct().collect()]
  dfArraySub = [d.where(d.sub_category == x) for x in listids_sub]
  num = 1

  for b in dfArraySub:
    #renames all columns to append a number
    for c in b.columns:
      if c not in ['category','sub_category','date']:
        column_name = str(c)+'_'+str(num)
        b = b.withColumnRenamed(str(c), str(c)+'_'+str(num))
        b = b.drop('sub_category')
    num += 1
    #if no df exists, create one and continually join new columns
    try:
      all_subs = all_subs.drop('sub_category').join(b.drop('sub_category'), on=['cateogry','date'], how='left')
    except:
      all_subs = b

  #Fixes missing columns on union
  try:
    try:
      diff_columns = list(set(all_cats.columns) - set(all_subs.columns))
      for d in diff_columns:
        all_subs = all_subs.withColumn(d, lit(None))
      all_cats = all_cats.union(all_subs)
    except:
      diff_columns = list(set(all_subs.columns) - set(all_cats.columns))
      for d in diff_columns:
        all_cats = all_cats.withColumn(d, lit(None))
      all_cats = all_cats.union(all_subs)

  except Exception as e:
    print e
    all_cats = all_subs
```

But this is very slow.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the logic behind ? how bed metrics are supposed to be in sales_1 and not in sales_2 ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your code ?

Comment: I group by category and then collect into an arrow - essentially splitting the big df into a bunch of little df's with just a single category.  Then I do the same thing for these smaller df's - but by sub category.  It is very expensive with the .collect() - this is much more pandas-esque code.  I am happy to scrap the entire thing and go with a much more spark oriented approach, like you posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is not really logical, but we can achieve this result using the pivot function. You need to precise your rules otherwise I can see a lot of cases it may fails.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.show()

+----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+
|      date| category|sub_category|metric_sales|metric_trans|
+----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+
|2018-01-01|furniture|         bed|         100|          75|
|2018-01-01|furniture|       chair|         110|          85|
|2018-01-01|furniture|       shelf|          35|          30|
|2018-02-01|furniture|         bed|          55|          50|
|2018-02-01|furniture|       chair|          45|          40|
|2018-02-01|furniture|       shelf|          10|          15|
|2018-01-01|      rug|      circle|           2|           5|
|2018-01-01|      rug|      square|           3|           6|
|2018-02-01|      rug|      circle|           3|           3|
|2018-02-01|      rug|      square|           4|           5|
+----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+



df.withColumn("fg", F.row_number().over(Window().partitionBy('date', 'category').orderBy("sub_category"))).groupBy('date', 'category', ).pivot('fg').sum('metric_sales', 'metric_trans').show()

+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|      date| category|1_sum(CAST(`metric_sales` AS BIGINT))|1_sum(CAST(`metric_trans` AS BIGINT))|2_sum(CAST(`metric_sales` AS BIGINT))|2_sum(CAST(`metric_trans` AS BIGINT))|3_sum(CAST(`metric_sales` AS BIGINT))|3_sum(CAST(`metric_trans` AS BIGINT))|
+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|2018-02-01|      rug|                                    3|                                    3|                                    4|                                    5|                                 null|                                 null|
|2018-02-01|furniture|                                   55|                                   50|                                   45|                                   40|                                   10|                                   15|
|2018-01-01|furniture|                                  100|                                   75|                                  110|                                   85|                                   35|                                   30|
|2018-01-01|      rug|                                    2|                                    5|                                    3|                                    6|                                 null|                                 null|
+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response.  I agree - there are some failure scenarios.  

To further complicate things, some categories have varying numbers of subcategories.

Am going to try this and will report back.

Comment: So this fails when I have 2 categories.  So I could have rugs category with square and circle sub cats. Thoughts?  I know it seems like an unorthodox transformation, but it is what I need.

Comment: I updated my original dataset to be more representative of the data I am working with, thanks.

Comment: Try changing `partitionBy('sub_category')` by `partitionBy('date', 'category', 'sub_category')`

Comment: So the issue is that the pivoting changes the columns to: bed_sum(CAST(`metric_sales` AS BIGINT))

vs. metric_sales_1.  So the table grows really wide (a column for each pivoted sub_category), when I want them to look like my excel output up top - stacked by metric 1, metric 2, etc.

Comment: BRILLIANT - thank you.  Works perfectly.  Really can't thank you enough. 45 minutes down to 30 seconds.